# Catch hacker in action

Tags: security, ftp

I have caught a hacker after looking through my site's FTP logs - it looks as if they have gleaned a list of passwords for several of my sites and are now connecting on a daily basis to upload spammy PHP files that perform header redirects to their sites. They always connect from the same IP address.

Blocking that IP and changing the FTP passwords is a given, but it seems so mundane and submissive. Is there anything I can do to this guy as he connects or once he's already in the system?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't say this, but place a virus in your FTP and rename it to `passwords`. Let him download that junk :)

Comment: hahahahahahah that is something I have done so satisfying to see a console popopen in metasploit when they open the file ;). However this is illegal sooo do it at your own risk.

Comment: Hmm, trying to avoid a long discussion though curious: is this illegal? I mean, the file is available on your own system without any intention of spreading it?

Comment: Heh. thx for downvote, I know this isn't a real question :)

Comment: @Aquillo the file is not persay illegal. I would have to say the act of penetrating their system is the illegal part, just my two cents.

Comment: Change your FTP port. Most script kiddies use a port scanner to scan a list of IP addresses for TCP services. They mostly look for port 21.

Comment: @Nomad101 Well, how about you leave that to the ****** that created the file in the first place :)

Comment: @dnelson that should be an answer, easy rep!

Comment: @Aquillo you are totally right just wanted the disclaimer :P

Comment: The question would probably be more appropriate for [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some recommendations:

1. Change your FTP port. Most script kiddies use a port scanner to scan a list of IP addresses for TCP services. They mostly look for port 21.
2. Disable root login for SSH.
3. You mentioned this before, but make sure your password is secure and not written down on a post-it note on you computer monitor.